# puppet can't get the right service status from centos5.3

Tags: service, puppet

when i disable puppet service ,centos5.3 system always have change: " Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet/Service[puppet]/ensure: ensure changed 'running' to 'stopped'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.15 seconds"

just say the code :

```
[root@xen-21206-vm02 ~]# puppet resource service puppet -d

Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDaemontools: file /usr/bin/svc does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderOpenrc: file /sbin/rc-service does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderLaunchd: file /bin/launchctl does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderGentoo: file /sbin/rc-update does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDebian: file /usr/sbin/update-rc.d does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRunit: file /usr/bin/sv does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderSystemd: file systemctl does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDaemontools: file /usr/bin/svc does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderOpenrc: file /sbin/rc-service does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderLaunchd: file /bin/launchctl does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderGentoo: file /sbin/rc-update does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDebian: file /usr/sbin/update-rc.d does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRunit: file /usr/bin/sv does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderSystemd: file systemctl does not exist
Debug: Executing '/sbin/service puppet status'
Debug: Executing '/sbin/chkconfig puppet'


service { 'puppet':
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => 'false',
}


[root@xen-21206-vm02 ~]# /sbin/service puppet status
puppet is stopped
[root@xen-21206-vm02 ~]# echo $?
3
```

this agent get the wrong service status.should

```
service { 'puppet':
  ensure => 'stopped',
  enable => 'false',
}
```

who can help me?

thks

Comment: Good analysis! This should not happen. CentOS `5.3` is rather ancient, yes? What version of Puppet is this?

Comment: puppet version: 3.2.3

Comment: That's really weird. Would you be willing to add additional debug output to your Puppet code files?